# KDE: how to detect default browser?

Tags: linux, kde

How does one detect/get the default browser on KDE?  I know that on Gnome one can use "gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command" but what about KDE?

Comment: From within a program or script? Or manually from the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a python script called [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) available which is a general purpose browser interface.  It includes a 'get' function which returns a controller to the default browser, which I think you could convert into a test appropriate for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

file `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`, section `[General]`, line `BrowserApplication`

Comment: It appears that this line no longer exists in current versions of KDE/Plasma.

Comment: It exists per user once you have done the configuration, see joe's answer below; otherwise see the system level configuration file `/etc/xdg/kdeglobals`.

Comment: It turned out that the .kde folder is named .kde4 on my system. Guess I didn't look very hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Choose the KMenu-> Control Center -> KDE Components -> Component Chooser -> web browser. It should show the present default browser and allow you to change it if you wish.

Comment: I am looking for a way to **detect** the default browser.

Comment: In my Kubuntu 11.04 it's in System settings -> Default Applications -> Web browser.