# Make a KDE shortcut to run the default browser

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, desktop-customization

I am new to KDE and would like to make shortcuts that run default applications.  For instance, I like `CTRL-ALT-I` to open my default browser.  I have found that I can create a custom shortcut directly to a specific browser, but I would like it to respect the default browser.  I have also tried a custom shortcut to `xdg-open http://www.google.com`, but this forces a specific page, ignoring the browser's default start page.

What is the "correct" way to do this in KDE?

Answer (score 1):

See [KDE: how to detect default browser?](https://superuser.com/questions/57367/kde-how-to-detect-default-browser)

Simply write a script that takes the configured browser's name out of the configuration file and executes it. Assign a global shortcut to this script.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, `xdg-open [protocol]://` will open that protocol's default handler.

```
xdg-open http:// 
xdg-open mailto://
xdg-open bitcoin://
```