# Manually setting KDE default applications without full KDE installation

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-workspace

I use Okular in an XFCE environment (archlinux). How can I set the default browser to use for opening URLs without installing a full KDE configuration panel?

As is, it does not use my default browser. From `strace` i believe it uses `/usr/lib/kf5/kioslave5`. I tried setting `~/.config/mimeapps.list` as per [this description](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/set-program-defaults-in-kde-plasma-5/):

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=vivaldi-stable.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=vivaldi-stable.desktop;
```

To no avail. I also tried `exo-web-browser.desktop`.

Note that [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/57367/kde-how-to-detect-default-browser) refers to KDE4, so I believe it does not apply.

To clarify: I have vivaldi set as preferred application / web browser as per the XFCE control panel. If I use `xdg-open http://...` it uses vivaldi. I do have two files `~/.local/share/xfce4/helpers/{custom-WebBrowser.desktop,vivaldi-stable.desktop}`, both referring to vivaldi.

Comment: Try the answer in the last entry in [this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1900454). If it doesn't help, do you have Preferred Applications in the Xfce Settings Manager? Or xfce4-settings-manager? And why avoid installing the KDE configuration panel?

Comment: The xfce settings all point to vivaldi. I clarified the details in an edit. I would prefer to keep my installation as lean as possible, while I don't mind getting dirty with editing some files. I also don't know which Archlinux package contains the KDE configuration panel - so for practical reasons I would appreciate a hint in that direction.

Comment: The archlinux package seems to be [xfce4-settings 4.14.2-1](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xfce4-settings/). If I understand right, you would rather not install it.

Comment: I do have `xfce4-settings`. I do not have the KDE configuration panel (package).

Comment: If you can open `xfce4-settings-manager`, then my linked answer might apply.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding here. I do have vivaldi set as preferred application / Web Browser in the `xfce4-settings-manager`. This works with some applications. But it does not work with Okular, a KDE application, which appears to use `kioslave5` that does not seem to respect the XFCE / XDG setting.

Comment: This is clearer now. Try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160918/clicking-links-in-pdfs-opened-with-okular-opens-abiword-instead-of-the-default).

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead installed `kcmshell5` from `kde-cli-tools` which also required a manual installation of `plasma-workspace` complete with 34 additional dependencies. Then I figured out the answer (see below) - which also relates to the specific answer you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `~/.config/mimeapps.list` / `[Default Applications]` was correct all along. However, Okular uses `text/html` instead of `x-scheme-handler/http(s)`. So for me, it looks like.

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=vivaldi-stable.desktop;
```

This can also be edited with `xfce4-mime-settings`.

It appears that Okular specifically first downloads all urls internally and only then decides how to handle it as per the mime type of the document.

Answer (score 2):

(*The full answer is given by the poster.
This answer only details the links that pointed to it.*)

The Ask Ubuntu post
[Clicking links in pdfs opened with Okular opens Abiword (instead of the default browser)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160918/clicking-links-in-pdfs-opened-with-okular-opens-abiword-instead-of-the-default)
contained the essential hint that Okular uses the file type of `text/html`,
rather than `html`, so this was the one to look for.

In my comments above I also mentioned the utility `xfce4-mime-settings`
that can edit these settings, which lives currently in the Arch Linux package
[xfce4-settings 4.14.2-1](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xfce4-settings/).